# How to call an external API from my API in Koa.js

Tags: node.js, rest, koa

I have an issue where I want to call an external API to verify a certain token coming from my frontend.

i.e

```js
router.post('/api/verifyToken', async (ctx, next) => {
   router.post('https://external-site.com/verify').then((response) => {
       if (response.success) {  console.log('Do some stuff') };
   })
})
```

How would I go about doing this with koa?

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood with the router itself.

In your router, you define a route where your clients can send HTTP requests and according to your business logic, you return the answers to them.

You can simply imagine `router.post('/api/verifyToken'` as an event listener. When a request comes in you run whatever is inside of it. It is not an HTTP client though.

If you want to send an external request you have to use an HTTP client for it.
There are a bunch of options:

- Built-in `http`/`https` package
- [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)
- [Node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)
- [GOT](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got)
- [Request](https://github.com/request/request)

And many others

One simple example how to do with Axios would be

```js
import axios from 'axios';

router.post('/api/verifyToken', async (ctx, next) => {
   try{
     const response = await axios.post('https://external-site.com/verify');
     // Do your stuff here
     console.log(response.data);
     ctx.body = response.data;
   }catch(e){
     ctx.status = 422;
     ctx.body = e.message;
   }
})
```